Cold data migration with sliding window stored procedure for partitioned tables in SQL Server
I am trying to write a sliding window stored procedure in SQL Server in order to migrate cold data to a cold storage. To do this, I planned on creating an "Archiving" table, that will store the (c)old data, and then MERGE my oldest partition and SPLIT the most recent partition to create a new one.
The tables are shown here:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Payload] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Destination] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Messages] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo_Archiving]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Payload] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Destination] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Messages__Archiving] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
GO

I have a few questions regarding this

In order to use the ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo] SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO [dbo].[Foo_Archiving] command, do I have to have the same partitions on both tables? And if so, do I specify the destination table partition at the end, such as ...TO [dbo].[Foo_Archiving] PARTITION 1?

When creating the indexes, do I create a nonclustered index for the primary keys (Id) and a clustered index for the partition key such as:


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__Foo]
GO
    
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_FooDate]
ON [dbo].[Foo](CreatedAt) -- or use (CreatedAt, Id) -- [?]
ON PS_FooPartitionScheme(CreatedAt)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__Foo] 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
    
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo_Archiving]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK__Foo__Archiving]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_FooArchivingDate] 
ON [dbo].[Foo_Archiving](CreatedAt) -- or use (CreatedAt, Id) -- [?]
ON PS_FooArchivingPartitionScheme([CreatedAt])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo_Archiving]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__Foo__Archiving] 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


(Continuation) Do the partition functions for both tables need to have the same number of partitions?

The partition schemes and functions and stored procedure I'm writing are as follows:
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_FooPartitionByDatetime (DATETIME)
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('2024-03-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-05-01');     
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_FooArchivingPartitionByDatetime (DATETIME)
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('2024-05-01');     
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_FooPartitionScheme
    AS PARTITION [PF_FooPartitionByDatetime]
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); 
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_FooArchivingPartitionScheme
    AS PARTITION [PF_FooPartitionByDatetime]
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo_Sliding_Window_Procedure
AS
    DECLARE 
        @merge_range INT, 
        @split_range INT
    
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Foo
    SWITCH PARTITION 1
    TO dbo.Foo_Archiving PARTITION 1 -- necessary?

    SELECT @merge_range = (SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(INT, value)
                           FROM sys.partition_range_values
                           ORDER BY boundary_id ASC)
                 
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_FooPartitionByDatetime]()
    MERGE RANGE (@merge_range)

    -- Good practice when splitting ranges
    ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_FooPartitionScheme
    NEXT USED [PRIMARY]

    SELECT @split_range = (SELECT TOP 1 value
                           FROM sys.partition_range_values
                           ORDER BY boundary_id DESC)

    -- Must convert to VARCHAR before DATEADD, or results in error : Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
    SELECT @split_range = CONVERT(INT, DATEADD(mm, 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @split_range)));

    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_FooPartitionByQuarter()
    SPLIT RANGE (@split_range)

    -- Truncate after all is done
    -- TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Foo_Archiving
GO

I'm getting an error on the stored procedure saying that my 'ALTER TABLE SWITCH' statement failed. The table [dbo].[Foo] is partitioned while index [PK__Foo] is not partitioned.
How do I correct this? And is there anything other than that which is not a good practice or is completely wrong?

Too broad, ask one specific question per question

It's two questions only, both related to the same objective, which is Cold data migration using a sliding window stored procedure.
You could just give me an answer instead of being counterproductive.
